# Multiple values in messagebox

Tags: vb.net, messagebox, multiline

I have that simple code

```
                    While reader.Read()
                    MessageBox.Show(reader(0).ToString().Trim())
                End While
```

Which returns 2 messagebox, one with value 'a' and another with 'b'. How do I modify it to have one messagebox giving me 'a' and 'b' in a single messagebox?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//declare variable_ and assign to empty string.
While reader.Read()
      variable_ = variable_ + reader(0).ToString().Trim()
End While

MessageBox.Show(variable_)
```

Comment: Thank you once again. That's what i wanted!